# Как сделать эфект переворачивания карточки при ховере?

Tags: css

Наводишь на неё она переворачивается и на обратной стороне текст написан

Comment: Берешь, прописываешь стили, она переворачивается. А если серьезно, добавьте в вопрос [mcve] ваши попытки, что у вас не получилось конкретно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нам понадобится:

1. Элемент карточки, с `position: relative`, при наведении на которой
   будет происходить вся магия.
2. Задний(`div.card__back`), который будет развернут при этом событии. `Position: absolute` и `z-index: 0`, чтобы быть за верхним блоком.
3. И, соответственно, верхний элемент(`div.card__front`), который сворачивается при наведении пользователя. НО, `z-index: 1` просто так работать не будет, добавляем `position: relative`

Теперь сама магия. Изначально задний блок у нас имеет `transform: rotatY(-180deg)`, это значит что он повернут относительно оси Y на 180 градусов, 
и с нашего угла обзора он отражен. А при наведении, уже верхний отражается на 180, а задний приходит в нормальное состояние, но это лишь анимация, тк их отображение переключает `z-index`.

Осталось лишь объяснить браузеру как отрисовывать эту анимацию, и я добавил кубик бизье для динамки анимации - `transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.2,.85,.4,1.275)`. А также указать одно свойство, которое используется редко, тк оно отвечает за отображение обратной стороны объекта `backface-visibility: hidden`

```css
.card {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
color: white;
}
.card__front{
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
background-color: cyan;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.2,.85,.4,1.275);
}
.card__back{
z-index: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
backface-visibility: hidden;
background-color: orange;
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.2,.85,.4,1.275);
}
.card:hover .card__back {
transform: rotateY(0deg);
z-index: 2;
}
.card:hover .card__front {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<div class="card__front">123</div>
<div class="card__back">321</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ответ достойный , только поясните что делает backface-visibility это свойство ...тогда ваш ответ будет супер